# Problems for autoload class namespace without composer

Tags: php, symfony, autoload, vendor

I've got some problems for **register a bundle in a Symfony2 project without Composer**.
In my company I can't use Composer due to proxy.

I succesfully install `FOSUserBundle` so I don't understand why it doesn't work with `KnpSnappyBundle`...

**My `vendor` tree :**

```
vendor/
    friendofsymfony/
        user-bundle/
            FOS/
                UserBundle/
                    FOSUserBundle.php
    knplabs/
        knp-snappy-bundle/
            Knp/
                Bundle/
                    SnappyBundle/
                        KnpSnappyBundle.php
```

**My `app/autoload.php` :**

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

/**
 * @var ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('FOS', __DIR__.'/../vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle');
$loader->add('Knp', __DIR__.'/../vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle');

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

**My `app/AppKernel.php` :**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new My\Bundle\OwnBundle\MyOwnBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle()
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

**The error message :**

```
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "KnpSnappyBundle" from namespace "Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle" in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\app\AppKernel.php line 25. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
```

Please help !

Comment: First things first: _"In my company I can't use Composer due to proxy"_? Could you please explain this a bit more? Given that [composer can be used from behind a proxy](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#http-proxy-or-http-proxy)

Comment: What sort of error message are you getting?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem : I've ever try everything and nothing works, the proxy seems really complex and it's impossible to get around.
Cerad : I've edit my question.

Comment: You can still use Composer autoloading without downloading dependencies by composer.

Comment: did you check the permission of the bundle dir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I found it !

So it was the good procedure but I forget to **clear the cache**.

```
php app/consoloe ca:cl -e=dev
```

After that I've still got an error :

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Knp\Snappy\GeneratorInterface' not found in /vendor/bundles/Knp/Bundle/SnappyBundle/Snappy/LoggableGenerator.php on line 14
```

Because without Composer a part of the KnpSnappyBundle is missing, so I [download the missing directories](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/tree/master/src/Knp/Snappy) on GitHub and **add in my `vendor`** :

```
vendor/
    knplabs/
        knp-snappy-bundle/
            Knp/
                Bundle/
                    SnappyBundle/
                        KnpSnappyBundle.php
                Snappy/
                    Exeption/
                    AbstractGenerator.php
                    GeneratorInterface.php
                    Image.php
                    Pdf.php
                    Process.php
```

Everything works, I didn't modify my `app/autoload.php` and my `app/AppKernel.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the problem solved.

**Composer:**

```
composer require knplabs/knp-snappy

composer require h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
```

**Symfony use:**

```
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;
```

**Code:**

```
$knpSnappyPdf = new Pdf();

$knpSnappyPdf->setBinary(__DIR__ . '/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64');

$html = $this->renderView('Pdf/template.html.twig', [
    ...
]);

$data = $knpSnappyPdf->getOutputFromHtml($html);
```

This bundle solved my problem with local images based on absolute path.